# Importing DWG from CAD to QGIS 3.28 failed

Tags: qgis, dwg

I have a problem with import DWG file from CAD. Unill today was no problem to import because every month I am adding something to CAD drawing (new walls from archaeology excavation) and then upload to QGIS on cadastre and orthophoto. Last 2-3 months everything was OK but today I get the message:

> Drawing import failed  ...

drawing file was meanwhile updated.

I was trying to change the folder, copy everything to new CAD file. I also tried with older version 2010,2007... but all the time get the same message.

What can I do?

Comment: What version of CAD? Vanilla AutoCAD? Map 3D? Civil 3D? Another brand?

Comment: Have you tried to use .dxf instead of .dwg?

Comment: I have ProgeCAD and with dwg was everything o.k. last 2-3 months

Comment: Do you mean that you added something new to your drawing and then import into QGIS started to fail? Can you revert to previous version of data?

Comment: Yes I add something new and yes I can import old version of drawing.

Comment: I cannot provide a real solution to this issue, but if you need an "emergency solution" you can try with ODA File Converter. It can generate .dxf files. Not sure if it could be enough in your situation since the result is not always very good, but we never know).

Comment: Tome, what exactly have you added to your .DWG file? Can you make a screenshot of your new features in the .DWG, please. Did you try to save your new .DWG file only with those new features and without the old features in that .DWG and then import that new .DWG file separately?